# Script for lazy-rendering in PhantomJS that sometimes locks phantomjs forever

Tags: phantomjs, anychart

I'm using phantomjs for rendering AnyChart v6 charts (http://6.anychart.com/) in PDF format.

An AnyChart v6 chart consists of an HTML file that calls an XML definition file through a Javascript library and renders it to SVG.

The XML definition file is the result of an on-the-fly complex processing, so the server can take up to few minutes to deliver the XML file to the Anychart javascript library.

My problem was to force phantomjs to wait for the XML file, so I came across this "twitter.js" script:

https://gist.github.com/cjoudrey/1341747

It works perfectly, except that sometimes it locks phantomjs forever and the only way to go on is to kill the Linux process.

It's a random behaviour, if I try again the same URL it works.

The server log shows that the XML file was correctly delivered, so it's not a server problem, it's a client problem.

Can you see a race condition or something in the "twitter.js" code that can lead to a phantomjs lock in some situations?

Comment: Cristian, please clarify: do you render AnyChart 6 HTML5 charts with Phantom JS?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but it may have something to do with http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-received.html

If the resource is large and sent by the server in multiple chunks, onResourceReceived will be invoked for every chunk received by PhantomJS.

Notice "stage : “start”, “end” (FIXME: other value for intermediate chunk?)"

Yet, forcedRenderTimeout should kill a page anyway.

Comment: Hello, do you think this is the cause of the lock?
Can you suggest a workaround?

Comment: The script writes a line on the console each time a resource is requested and each time a resource is received.
I noticed that when phantomjs locks the console doesn't show the XML resource neither as requested nor as received.
Looks like a JS engine bug to me, but I'm not able to understand why and when it happens.